# Get data based on the greatest ID using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The stored procedure returns the latest customer ID.

It returns the latest customer ID by passing two variables. In this case one variable is the the unit number and the other the facility policy number.

Once again thank you guys!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Getcustomerinfo] (@UN  VARCHAR(20), 
                                          @FPN VARCHAR(20)) 
AS `enter code here`
  BEGIN 
      SELECT customers.id, 
             customers.full_name, 
             customers.address, 
             customers.city, 
             customers.state, 
             customers.zip_code, 
             customers.phone_number, 
             customers.email_address, 
             policys_transactions.unit_number 
      FROM   customers 
             INNER JOIN policy_facility_customer 
                     ON customers.id = policy_facility_customer.customer_id 
             INNER JOIN policys_transactions 
                     ON policy_facility_customer.cert_number = 
                        policys_transactions.cert_number 
      WHERE  ( policys_transactions.unit_number = @UN 
               AND policys_transactions.facility_policy_number = @FPN ) 
      ORDER  BY customers.ID DESC 
  END
```

Comment: Right now you are sorting by Effective_Date, change that to Customer.ID

Comment: Double check your POLICYS_Transactions.Effective_Date. If you have multiple customers with the same or incorrect date it may return data in a different order than you expect. Also, you can add LIMIT 1 to the end of your ORDER BY clause to just return the top record found.

Comment: how do you define latest customer ID? by a date or your ID is running no? [ORDER BY  POLICYS_Transactions.Effective_Date DESC ] ===> [ORDER BY  POLICYS_Transactions.Effective_Date, CUSTOMERS.ID DESC LIMIT 1]

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH GUYS!!! I took out the sorting by Effective_Date and changed it to Customer.ID and it gives me exactly what I want.